# How to allow multiple special characters in a Path Variable in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to allow multiple special characters in a PathVariable in spring controller, how to handle this??

for ex:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/servlet/test/testMethod/married%20on%2004%2F03%2F2012
```

how do I decode this in my spring controller, or allow these special characters in PathVaraible?

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass data to Controller? recommendation is pass as request params separated with '&'.
In controller, you can get the data as simple as fetching from Map.